# How to set default value to aws_iam_policy with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I want to set aws policy dynamically. Set variables to call `aws_iam_policy` resource. The variable file as

variables.tf

```
variable "name" {
  default = ""
  type = string
}

variable "policy" {
  default = ""
  type = string
}
```

In main.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_policy" {
  name   = var.name
  policy = var.policy
}
```

When run `tflint`

name var got:

```
Error: name must be 1 characters or higher (aws_iam_policy_invalid_name)
Error: "" does not match valid pattern ^[\w+=,.@-]+$ (aws_iam_policy_invalid_name)
```

policy var got:

```
Error: policy must be 1 characters or higher (aws_iam_policy_invalid_policy)
Error: "" does not match valid pattern ^[\x{0009}\x{000A}\x{000D}\x{0020}-\x{00FF}]+$ (aws_iam_policy_invalid_policy)
```

Can't it set to "" string if don't set policy by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed policy name **can't be empty** string. At [least 1 character](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-policyname) is required following `[\w+=,.@-]+` pattern.

But to **auto generate** name if you have empty string, you can try the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_policy" {
  count  = var.policy != "" ? 1 : 0 
  name   = var.name != "" ? var.name : null
  policy = var.policy
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it should be `name   = var.name != "" ? var.name : null`. And is it possible to use `count = var.policy ? 1 : 0` to check if policy variable has been set, to select if run this resource task or not?

Comment: @Miantian Yes, I corrected the answer. And yes, you can use could as well to skip the creation of the policy if not given.

Comment: Do you know how to use it?

Comment: @Miantian I updated the answer, and it does not work?

Comment: It works now. I set count by a wrong way just now. Thank you.